# Как выделить всю строку через Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Имеем таблицу с данными. Где каждая строка отдельная запись. С данными записями я провожу определенную операцию. Для этого написан скрипт. Но для запуска скрипта мне необходимо выделить всю сроку и только после этого запустить скрипт. Сейчас я делаю это (выделяю всю сроку) руками или через горячие клавиши (SHIFT+пробел). Хотелось бы автоматизировать данный процесс.

То есть выбираем любую ячейку, запускаем скрипт и он выделяет нам всю строку (в которой расположена данная ячейка). А дальше я уже имеющимся скриптом работаю с выделенным диапазоном.

Я не специалист по Google таблицам. В Excel методом проб и ошибок удалось создать макрос, который при запуске расширял диапазон с одной выбранной ячейки до необходимого количества столбцов. В Google Script у меня не выходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Получить объект range на основании выделенной ячейки, например через [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRange())

2) У полученного объекта range получаем номер строки через [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRow())

3) Выделяем полученную строку, например, через [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String))

Comment: Спасибо! Я мыслил точно так же, но видимо где-то ошибся в построении кода. Сейчас все получилось.